# use sed to join lines from a table

Tags: sed

I have below table from my query, my separator is `+` however it is creating new lines under DESCRIPTION as shown in example below:

```
TYPE+DESCRIPTION+PRIORITY+DATE
1+text1+HIGH+Aug 15
+text2  
2+text+LOW+Aug 11
3+text+LOW+Aug 11
4+text1+HIGH+Aug 15
+text2  
+text3
```

how will i make it looks like below using sed

```
TYPE    DESCRIPTION      PRIORITY DATE
1       text1 text2      HIGH     Aug 15
2       text             LOW      Aug 11
3       text             LOW      Aug 11
4       text text2 text3 HIGH     Aug 15
```

I have tried:

```
sed -n '1{h;n};/^ *+ */{s// /;H;n};{x;s/\n//g;p};${x;p}'
```

but gives me error (sed: command garbled), thanks

Comment: Why sed particularly? Are you open to using other tools?

Comment: Shouldn't the 2nd column on the 4th row be "text1 text2 text3"? Also, can the output table be simplified to have only one character as the delimiter, say ','?

Comment: @seshoumara, yes you are correct, 4th row should be text1 text2 text3 on 2nd column and any delimiter will do, thanks

Comment: Again: Can it be another tool, such as awk? It would give less headache. And do you have `column` utility?

Comment: hi, yes any tool will do, appreciate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Went back and read what differences may be between our versions of sed and re-wrote it from scratch. Hope this works:

```
:r
    $!N
    y:+:,:
    /\n,/{
        s:^\([^,]\{1,\},[^,]\{1,\}\)\([^\n]\{1,\}\)\n,\([^ \n]\{1,\}\).*$:\1 \3\2:
        br
    }
    $!P
    $!D
```

**Output:**

```
TYPE,DESCRIPTION,PRIORITY,DATE
1,text1 text2,HIGH,Aug 15
2,text,LOW,Aug 11
3,text,LOW,Aug 11
4,text1 text2 text3,HIGH,Aug 15
```

Comment: My answer makes the assumption that the description texts do not contain space or plus. Let me know if this is not acceptable.

Comment: thanks, but it says , sed: illegal option -- r . I use SunOS

Comment: no luck , both doesn't work for me :(

Comment: Perhaps you don't have GNU sed, I'm on Ubuntu. Try this instead: `sed -z ':l;s:^\([^+]\++[^+]\+\)\([^\n]\+\)\n+\([^ \n]\+\).*:\1 \3\2:m;tl;y:+:,:' input.txt`.

Comment: yeah,i dont have GNU sed, the -z is illegal option too

Comment: Rewrote the script, this time in a file. Run with sed -f script.sed input.txt.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk '
    BEGIN{OFS=FS="+"}
    {sub(/[[:blank:]]+$/,"")}  #Removes trailing blanks
    NF==4{print line;line=$0}
    NF==2{x=$2;$0=line;$2=$2" "x;line=$0}
    END{print line}
' file | column -ts "+"
```

The main idea behind it is that if `NF==2`, then put the second field `$2` in the second field of the preceding line. So what happens is

```
1+text1+HIGH+Aug 15 #Puts this in "line" variable
+text2              #Transfer 2nd field to "line" second field
# Resulting in...
1+text1 text2+High+Aug 15
```

`column` removes the `+` from the output to generate this fine final output:

```
TYPE  DESCRIPTION        PRIORITY  DATE
1     text1 text2        HIGH      Aug 15
2     text               LOW       Aug 11
3     text               LOW       Aug 11
4     text1 text2 text3  HIGH      Aug 15
```

Answer (score 4):

Making a "field agnostic" `awk`

```
tac file | awk 'BEGIN{FS="+"}
    {flds=(NF>flds)?NF:flds;for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {f=(length($i)>0)?gensub(/ +$/,"","g",$i)" ":"";fld[i]=f fld[i]}}
    $1>0{for (i=1; i<=flds; i++) printf fld[i]"+"; printf "\n"; delete fld}' | 
    tac | column -ts "+"

TYPE   DESCRIPTION         PRIORITY   DATE     
1      text1 text2         HIGH       Aug 15   
2      text                LOW        Aug 11   
3      text                LOW        Aug 11   
4      text1 text2 text3   HIGH       Aug 15
```

**Walkthrough**

Turn the file around so that you know it's time to print when $1 is not blank and set `FS`

```
tac file | awk 'BEGIN{FS="+"}
```

Keep count of the max no of `flds`, loop over the fields trimming them and checking for blanks, load them into an array by field to aggregate them

```
    {flds=(NF>flds)?NF:flds;for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {f=(length($i)>0)?gensub(/ +$/,"","g",$i)" ":"";fld[i]=f fld[i]}}
```

If `$1` is non-blank then output the line and reset the array

```
    $1>0{for (i=1; i<=flds; i++) printf fld[i]"+"; printf "\n"; delete fld}' |
```

Pipe through `tac` to turn it around and use `column` to prettify it

```
    tac | column -ts "+"
```

**Edit**

Really didn't like the second loop, stopping to `gensub` every field when you can hit it with the `sed` hammer as it is piped and that the tests can be simplified. Felt inelegant.

So here is a *golfed* version that just *feels* better to me:

```
tac file | awk 'BEGIN{FS="+"}
    {flds=(NF>flds)?NF:flds;
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {fld[i]=$i" "fld[i];
        if ($1) printf fld[i]"+"}}
    $1{ printf "\n"; delete fld}' |
    sed -E "s/  +/ /g" | tac | column -ts "+"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -0pe 'while(s/(.*?)\+(.*?)\+(.*)\n\+(.*)/$1+$2 $4+$3/g){}' file
```

- `perl -0`  - slurp all the input
- `s/(.*?)\+(.*?)\+(.*)\n\+(.*)/$1+$2 $4+$3/g` transforms `A+B+...C\n+D` in `A+B D+...C` while possible.

Comment: To slurp all the input the syntax is `-0777`. `-0` is for NUL-delimited records.

Comment: You may want to review your other answers as well. See for instance [Sort file by group of lines](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/524051) that also incorrectly refers to `-0` as a slurp mode.